# añadir un elemento a la vez, 1 sola vez por cada elemento

Tags: javascript

lo que hace al 1er boton me añade el pulsado
apreto boton por 2da vez  me añade el anterior mas el pulsado
apreto el boton 3ra vez me añade el sucesor del anterior el anterior y el actual

lo que necesito es agregar
apreto boton 1era vez me añade el pulsado
apreto boton por 2da vez  me añada el pulsado
apreto el boton 3ra vez me añade el pulsado

y mostrando mensajes al usuario

```
   function addToItem(e){

 Items.push(Items[Itms.length - 1]);

  let sinRepetidos = Items.filter((valorActual, indiceActual, arreglo) => {
 correcto = arreglo.findIndex(valorDelArreglo =>
  JSON.stringify(valorDelArreglo) === JSON.stringify(valorActual)
 ) === indiceActual;
 if (correcto)
   console.log('se ingreso correctamente', valorActual)
else
   console.log('repetido', valorActual)
 return correcto 
})

console.log(sinRepetidos)


  renderItem()

}
  function renderItrm(){
   

 var Content=""
  Items.map(item => {
}

 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te veo complicado con este asunto, por ejemplo para buscar un repetido conviertes a JSON, cuando deberías hacer algo asi:

```
 let item = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
 if(item) console.log("Repetido");
 else console.log("NO Repetido");
```

Luego los índices que si el primero, que se te repiten, que sacar el último, etc. Cuando la lógica del carrito es simple.

1. Seleccionas un producto
2. Si el producto existe en el carrito le sumas 1 a la cantidad
3. Si no existe lo agregas al carrito
4. renderizas para mostrar los cambios. En el ejemplo a continuación se renderiza solo lo modificado (el código sale más fácil si hubiera renderizado TODO cada vez, pero es ineficiente). Entonces si el producto existe en el carrito se renderiza esa fila del carrito, si no existe se agrega una nueva fila. Y al final del todo se renderiza el item agregado de la lista de productos para cambiar la disponibilidad

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo de esto

```js
const Productos = [
{ id: 1, codigo: 1, nombre: "Producto 1",cantidad_disponible: 3,talla: 20, talla_ropa: "X"},
{ id: 2, codigo: 2, nombre: "Producto 2",cantidad_disponible: 4,talla: 40, talla_ropa: "XL"},
{ id: 3, codigo: 3, nombre: "Producto 3",cantidad_disponible: 5,talla: 30, talla_ropa: "S"},
];

const carrito = [];

//función para convertir un template con variables --> https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152
function interpolate(template, params) {
 template = template.toString().trim()
 const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
 const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
 const keys = Object.keys(params);
 const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
 return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
}
//==========================================================



function addToCarritoItem(id){
  let itemProducto = Productos.find(a=> a.id==id);
  

  
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  if(itemCarrito){
     //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
    if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
      return;
    }
   itemCarrito.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
  }
  else{
    itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
    itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
    itemCarrito.precio=0;
    carrito.push(itemCarrito);
    
    //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
    carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
  }
  
  
  
  updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
}

//renderiza todos los productos
function renderProductos(){
  productos_content.innerHTML="";
  for(let item of Productos){
    productos_content.innerHTML+=interpolate(templateItem.innerHTML, item);
  }
}

const GetMax = id => Productos.find(a=> a.id==id).cantidad_disponible;

function updatecantidad(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);

  document.getElementById("Q_"+id).innerText=GetMax(id)-valor;
  itemCarrito.cantidad=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateprecio(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  itemCarrito.precio=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateTotal(item){
 document.getElementById("T_"+item.id).innerText= item.cantidad * item.precio;
}

renderProductos();
```

```html
<template id="templateItem">
 <tr id="P_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td id="Q_${id}">${cantidad_disponible}</td>
  <td><button onclick="addToCarritoItem(${id})">Añadir al carro</button></td>
 </tr>
</template>

<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" oninput="updatecantidad(${id},this.value)" max="${GetMax(id)}" min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}" oninput="updateprecio(${id},this.value)" min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template>


<h1>Productos</h1>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="productos_content">
    
  <tbody>
</table>

<h1>Carrito</h1>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Precio</td>
      <td>Total</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="carrito_content">
    
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: esta muy bueno, pero lo que necesito es, la cantidad y el precio lo define la persona frente al pc a travez de inputs

Comment: @FelipeBarros No me lo imagino....puedes pegarme una foto de la UI??

Comment: abajo de mi pregunta esta lo q necesito

Comment: haber si me ayudas con mi codigo, te lo pondre a continuacion en mi pregunta, tiene mescla de php

Comment: @FelipeBarros solo tienes que cambiar los `template` para ajustarlo a tu propósito y la verdad pienso que se me pasó la mano con el ejemplo que te puse porque es básicamente un carrito completo, entiendo que tu problema es puntual pero el código que has puesto no contiene lo necesario para reproducir el problema, por eso yo me he animado a generar un código completo, si esto no ha sido de ayuda lo lamento, pero quizás le sirva a alguien más, por mi parte hasta aquí llego