# carrito de yussef intento de traspaso de codigo a mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, php

este es un intento de la respuesta planteada mas abajo, donde tengo 2 tabs y con interpolate capturo lo que es el template lo cual con php llevo las variables a php para que sean procesadas con el elemento y capturando con  textcontent al dar al boton añadir
y bueno el problema es que no encuentra el id del carrito me sale undefined
al precionar añadir este deberia de añadirse en el tabs 2
**al añadir este id se captura hacia el metodo, eso ya esta.**

```html
     <html>
       <head>
  <title>Untitled-2</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">  

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
   }
   input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }

    </style>

     </head>
     <body>


   <template id="templateRowCarrito">
   <tr id="C_${id}">
   <td>${nombre}</td>
   <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" 
  oninput="updatecantidad(${id},this.value)" max="${GetMax(id)}" min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}" oninput="updateprecio(${id},this.value)" min="0"> 
 </td>
   <td id="T_${id}"></td>
   </tr>
   </template>


        
  <section class="section">
     <div class="tabs">
       <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

  <table id="articulos"class="table">
    <thead>
       
        <tr>
        <TH>id </TH>
        <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>Codigo</TH>
            <TH>producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>Añadir</TH>
         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  id="productos_content">
    
        @foreach($Variables as $e)
        <?php
            # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
            printf('<tr class="tr" id="P_' . $e->id_productos . '">');
        ?>
        
        <td class="id">{{$e->id_productos}}</td>
            <td class="id">{{$e->id_productos}}</td>
            <td class="codigo">{{$e->codigo}}</td>
            <td class="nombre"> {{$e->nombre}}</td>
            <?php
            # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
            printf('<td class="cantidad_disponible" id="Q_' . $e->id_productos .'">'. $e->cantidad_disponible.'</td>');
        ?>

           
            
          <td class="td">
        <?php
            # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
            printf('<button class="button" onclick="addToCarritoItem(' . $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir</button>');
        ?>
    </td>
        </tr>
       
    @endforeach
    
    </tbody>
</table>

  </div>



    <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">

     <form id="form2" action="javascript:validar()">

    <input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" disabled />


  <table id="tabla" class="table">
    
       
        <tr>
        <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>Codigo</TH>
            <TH>producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
          
           
            <TH>Añadir </TH>
            <TH>Añadir </TH>  
            <TH>Añadir </TH>
        </tr>
           <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
           <div class="card shadow mb-1 bg-dark rounded" style="width: 20rem;">

    
       </div>
    </tbody>
    </table>

       <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

       </div>
    
    </div>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
const tabSystem = {
init(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
        Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
            child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
            });
            if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
            }
        });
    });
},
toggle(targetId){
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
        contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
    })
},
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()




const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(Clickbutton)




const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
let carrito = []

Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', addToCarritoItem)
})

 const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .id').textContent;
  const codigo = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .codigo').textContent;
  const nombre = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .nombre').textContent;
  const cantidad_disponible = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td >.talla').textContent;
  const talla_ropa = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td >.talla_ropa').textContent;
  //const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;

  const Productos = {
  id: id_prod,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    talla: talla,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropa,
    cantidad:1
//    //img: itemImg,
   
   
  }




//función para convertir un template con variables --> https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152
function interpolate(template, params) {
  template = template.toString().trim()
  const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
  const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
  const keys = Object.keys(params);
  const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
  return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
 }
function addToCarritoItem(id){
//  // Guardamos la variable en una constante de js
//  const id_producto = id;
//  // Creamos una alerta donde mostramos el contenido de la constante
//  alert("El id del producto es: " + id_producto);

const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .id').textContent;
const codigo = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos >  #productos_content > .tr > .codigo').textContent;
const nombre = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos >  #productos_content > .tr > .nombre').textContent;
const cantidad_disponible = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos >  #productos_content > .tr > .cantidad_disponible').textContent;
const talla = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos >  #productos_content > .tr > .talla').textContent;
const talla_ropa = document.querySelector('#first-tab > #articulos >  #productos_content > .tr >.talla_ropa').textContent;
//const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;

let item = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
 if(item) console.log("Repetido");
 else console.log("NO Repetido");


let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  if(itemCarrito){
     //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
    if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
      return;
    }
   itemCarrito.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
  }
  else{
    itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
    itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
    itemCarrito.precio=0;
    carrito.push(itemCarrito);
    
    //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
    carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
  }
  
  
  
  updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
}

//renderiza todos los productos
function renderProductos(){
  productos_content.innerHTML="";
  for(let item of Productos){
    productos_content.innerHTML+=interpolate(templateItem.innerHTML, item);
  }
}

const GetMax = id => Productos.find(a=> a.id==id).cantidad_disponible;

function updatecantidad(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);

  document.getElementById("Q_"+id).innerText=GetMax(id)-valor;
  itemCarrito.cantidad=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateprecio(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  itemCarrito.precio=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateTotal(item){
 document.getElementById("T_"+item.id).innerText= item.cantidad * item.precio;
}

renderProductos();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon.ico" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">  

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }

</style>

</head>
<body>


<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" oninput="updatecantidad(${id},this.value)" max="${GetMax(id)}" min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}" oninput="updateprecio(${id},this.value)" min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template>


            
<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

     
      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
                <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
             
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
        
            @foreach($Variables as $e)
            <?php
                # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
                printf('<tr class="tr" id="P_' . $e->id_productos . '">');
            ?>
            
            <td class="id">{{$e->id_productos}}</td>
                <td class="id">{{$e->id_productos}}</td>
                <td class="codigo">{{$e->codigo}}</td>
                <td class="nombre"> {{$e->nombre}}</td>
                <?php
                # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
                printf('<td class="cantidad_disponible" id="Q_' . $e->id_productos .'">'. $e->cantidad_disponible.'</td>');
            ?>

               
                
                <td class="talla"> {{$e->talla}}</td>
                <td class="talla_ropa"> {{$e->talla_ropa}}<td>
              
        
              <td class="td">
            <?php
                # Creamos el boton con la función de php PRINTF y concatenamos la variable para enviarla a javascript
                printf('<button class="button" onclick="addToCarritoItem(' . $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir</button>');
            ?>
        </td>
            </tr>
           
        @endforeach
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
      </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">

      <form id="form2" action="javascript:validar()">
      

<input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" disabled />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
        
           
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
                <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
                <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>  
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               <div class="card shadow mb-1 bg-dark rounded" style="width: 20rem;">

        
           </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

adjunto link

[añadir un elemento a la vez, 1 sola vez por cada elemento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595492/a%c3%b1adir-un-elemento-a-la-vez-1-sola-vez-por-cada-elemento/595509#595509)